# Getting cl_flushentitypacket even after wired connection and low ping

Tags: counter-strike, windows-10, counter-strike-condition-zero

I'm getting that annoying `cl_flushentitypacket` error after every 5-10 seconds in my game. I am using a wired connection and my ping stays between 55-60, but sometimes it just disappears ( when it becomes insanely high I guess).

I have Win 10 on my PC and I'm well aware of the fact that automatic updates cannot be disabled and hence they do eat up a bit of speed (not on WiFi though, I've set my connection as metered). My PC is also more than required (much more) to run the game.

My internet connection is 1Mbps download and 512Kbps upload, I know that's slow but should be enough for CS at least right? From all I know, I think that I'm experiencing heavy lag spikes. I have no idea how to resolve it.

No torrents or downloads are running in the background, no browsers nothing that I am aware of. Windows Defender ran a full scan and reported no viruses whatsoever.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I am sure reinstalling will fix the problem.(It happened to me too)

Comment: @DeMize tried that, Didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You have basically covered all the areas from which you could get a cl_flushentitypacket error, so, the only suspect might be your rates for that server. You can ask the server for the rates and that might solve the problems you are facing. If the problem still persists, it maybe because you have a defected copy of Counter Strike 1.6. Try a different copy.